# How do I get itouch-icons in Android?

Tags: android, html, webview, bitmap

I’m writing an android app that downloads and saves the "apple-touch-icon" png image for any site the user may navigate to within my webview. I’m currently using JSOUP to get the html document, parse the document, and locate the link identified by:  rel="apple-touch-icon". For example, the link for stack overflow looks like this:

```
rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
```

I have this working, but it’s exceptionally slow. Essentially I’m downloading the same page twice, once to display it in webview, and a second time to parse it with JSOUP, and then it downloads the image.  Is there a way I can get the link I need from the document already in my webview, rather than downloading the page again and then parsing it?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that within the WebChromeClient class there's this method:

```
public void onReceivedTouchIconUrl (WebView view, String url, boolean precomposed)
```

which gives me exactly what I need.